# Invalid Cast Exception when using an interface as generic type

Tags: c#, generics, interface, unity-game-engine, .net

So I am not sure if this is a C# generics issue I don't understand or whether it has something to do with the Unity compiler not being able to handle it. I come from C++ and am slightly experienced with c# but not with generics.

So onto the issue:
I have a generic class called TurnOrderQueue. in short it is a custom Queue that orders things based on some values that are passed in with it. (It is in a namespace called TurnOrderQueueNS)

I have an empty(for now) interface called IActor which is to represent things that can take actions in a turn based game.

Finally I have a TurnOrderManager that handles everything with turn order and owns a TurnOrderQueue.

When I attempt to instantiate the TurnOrderQueue using IActor as the type I get an invalid cast exception

```
public TurnOrderQueueNS.TurnOrderQueue<IActor> TurnOrder = new TurnOrderQueueNS.TurnOrderQueue<IActor>();
```

The Exception I get at runtime is: 
InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
TurnOrderQueueNS.TurnOrderQueue`1[IActor]..ctor ()
TurnManager..ctor ()

Can you not use Interfaces as the type with generics in C# or am  i missing something?

Per Request Here is the TurnOrderQueue.cs
edit: removed much of the class to show the meat of the issue

```
     public class TurnOrderQueue<t>: IComparer{
     private SortedList<QueueItem<t>,t> turnOrderList;
     private int currentTurnIndex = 0;


     #region IComparer implementation
     int IComparer.Compare (object x, object y)
     {
         return Compare ((QueueItem<t>)x, (QueueItem<t>)y );
     }
     #endregion

    }
    public struct QueueItem<t>
    {
     public int priorityValue;
     public int tieBreakerValue;
     public t item;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post your TurnOrderQueue interface

Comment: TurnOrderQueue is not an interface but I added it to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception you get is not related to `IActor` interface or generic parameter type.

In constructor you are trying to cast `this` to `IComparer<QueueItem<t>>`.
To be able to do that your class should implement `IComparer<QueueItem<t>>`.

```
public class TurnOrderQueue<t> : IComparer<QueueItem<t>>
{
    <skipped>

    public TurnOrderQueue()
    {
        turnOrderList = new SortedList<QueueItem<t>, t>(this);
    }

    public int Compare(QueueItem<t> item1, QueueItem<t> item2)
    {
        <skipped>
    }
 }
```

Comment: wow duh lol. I think I got tunnel vision on that one. Thank you soo much for the help!